# In React what would cause networking (fetch, xmlhttprequest) to fail never calling a callback or producing an error?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, xmlhttprequest, fetch, babeljs

I'm upgrading a react-native project from 0.67 to 0.70.  I created a brand new project with npx react init.  I then tediously brought over the code and configuration.

When I run the project on simulator or real device any fetch or xmlhttp request just hangs never calling the callback.  Or if using async never getting a response.

What could cause this?  Here is sample code:

```
    NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
      console.log("App Connection type", state.type);
      console.log("App Is connected?", state.isConnected);

      const url="https://google.com"
      console.log('App getting trendingData from server',{url,req,})
      async function fetchit(){
        console.log('App in fetchit',state.isConnected)
        try {
          console.log('App in fetchit try',state.isConnected)
          let response=await fetch(url,req)
          console.log('App got response from server',{ok:response.ok,})
        }
        catch (e){
          console.log('App error getting data from server',{e})
        }
      }
      fetchit()
  }
```

The first and second logs say state.type='wifi' and state.isConnected=true
The last log seen is: 'App in fetchit try'
We never see 'App got response...'

Does same when using fetch().then()...

Answer (score 1):

After many many hours trying all kinds of things and doing many searches I found the problem (although I don't understand why this fixes it).

My project requires @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties

I was passing {"loose":false}

Once I changed this to `{"loose":true}` all my fetches started to work again.

See below for how I came to try this

.babelrc contents:

```
{
  "presets": [
      ["@babel/preset-react"]
  ],
  "plugins": [
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

To find this I created another new react-native project and added the sample code from the question.  In this project it worked so that proved it wasn't something with simulator, machine, etc.

Then I brought over the code from my real project.  The sample fetch still worked but the project didn't run because of the missing .babelrc

Once I brought over the .babelrc the fetches stopped working.  aha!

So then I removed the lines in .babelrc one at a time (running yarn start --reset-cache in between each time).  Once I removed the plugin-proposal-class-properties line the fetches started working.  Then I put it back but changed loose:false to true.  Fetches continued to work.  I'm not sure what implications that change has but if I find out I'll update this answer.

Hope this saves somebody some time!  I burned more than 2 days.